# Recover files after find . -delete

Tags: bash, find, data-recovery

After accidently deleting files in the wrong dir, using `find . -delete`, is there anyway to recover the files or are they permanently removed from the filesystem?

EDIT:

I am hoping to find a relatively specific answer, rather than the recovery of a single file. There are several files deleted and manual restoration of each, individually, isn't a viable option.

Comment: in short: only if you have a backup. or snapshot on a filesystem that supports snapshots (e.g. btrfs and zfs)

Comment: debugfs is also an option when trying to retrieve deleted files.